# Monadic approach to estimating PI in scala

Tags: scala, monads, scala-cats

I'm trying to understand how to leverage monads in scala to solve simple problems as way of building up my familiarity. One simple problem is estimating PI using a functional random number generator. I'm including the code below for a simple stream based approach.

I'm looking for help in translating this to a monadic approach. For example, is there an idiomatic way convert this code to using the state (and other monads) in a stack safe way?

```
trait RNG {
    def nextInt: (Int, RNG)
    def nextDouble: (Double, RNG)
}

case class Point(x: Double, y: Double) {
    val isInCircle = (x * x + y * y) < 1.0
}

object RNG {
    def nonNegativeInt(rng: RNG): (Int, RNG) = {
      val (ni, rng2) = rng.nextInt
      if (ni > 0) (ni, rng2)
      else if (ni == Int.MinValue) (0, rng2)
      else (ni + Int.MaxValue, rng2)
    }

    def double(rng: RNG): (Double, RNG) = {
      val (ni, rng2) = nonNegativeInt(rng)
      (ni.toDouble / Int.MaxValue, rng2)
    }


    case class Simple(seed: Long) extends RNG {
      def nextInt: (Int, RNG) = {
      val newSeed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFL
      val nextRNG = Simple(newSeed)
      val n = (newSeed >>> 16).toInt
      (n, nextRNG)
    }

    def nextDouble: (Double, RNG) = {
      val (n, nextRNG) = nextInt
      double(nextRNG)
    }
  }
}

object PI {
    import RNG._

    def doubleStream(rng: Simple):Stream[Double] = rng.nextDouble match {
        case (d:Double, next:Simple) => d #:: doubleStream(next)
    }

    def estimate(rng: Simple, iter: Int): Double = {
        val doubles = doubleStream(rng).take(iter)
        val inside = (doubles zip doubles.drop(3))
            .map { case (a, b) => Point(a, b) }
            .filter(p => p.isInCircle)
            .size * 1.0
        (inside / iter) * 4.0
    }
}

// > PI.estimate(RNG.Simple(10), 100000)
// res1: Double = 3.14944
```

I suspect I'm looking for something like `replicateM` from the `Applicative` monad in cats but I'm not sure how to line up the types or how to do it in a way that doesn't accumulate intermediate results in memory. Or, is there a way to do it with a `for` comprehension that can iteratively build up `Point`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Id you want to iterate using monad in a stack safe way, then there is a `tailRecM` method implemented in `Monad` type class:

```
// assuming random generated [-1.0,1.0]
def calculatePi[F[_]](iterations: Int)
                     (random: => F[Double])
                     (implicit F: Monad[F]): F[Double] = {
  case class Iterations(total: Int, inCircle: Int)
  def step(data: Iterations): F[Either[Iterations, Double]] = for {
    x <- random
    y <- random
    isInCircle = (x * x + y * y) < 1.0
    newTotal = data.total + 1
    newInCircle = data.inCircle + (if (isInCircle) 1 else 0)
  } yield {
    if (newTotal >= iterations) Right(newInCircle.toDouble / newTotal.toDouble * 4.0)
    else Left(Iterations(newTotal, newInCircle))
  }
  // iterates until Right value is returned
  F.tailRecM(Iterations(0, 0))(step)
}
calculatePi(10000)(Future { Random.nextDouble }).onComplete(println)
```

It uses by-name param because you could try to pass there something like `Future` (even though the `Future` is not lawful), which are eager, so you would end up with evaluating the same thing time and time again. With by name param at least you have the chance of passing there a recipe for side-effecting random. Of course, if we use `Option`, `List` as a monad holding our "random" number, we should also expect funny results.

The correct solution would be using something that ensures that this `F[A]` is lazily evaluated, and any side effect inside is evaluated each time you need a value from inside. For that you basically have to use some of Effects type classes, like e.g. `Sync` from Cats Effects.

```
def calculatePi[F[_]](iterations: Int)
                     (random: F[Double])
                     (implicit F: Sync[F]): F[Double] = {
  ...
}
calculatePi(10000)(Coeval( Random.nextDouble )).value
calculatePi(10000)(Task( Random.nextDouble )).runAsync
```

Alternatively, if you don't care about purity that much, you could pass side effecting function or object instead of `F[Int]` for generating random numbers.

```
// simplified, hardcoded F=Coeval
def calculatePi(iterations: Int)
               (random: () => Double): Double = {
  case class Iterations(total: Int, inCircle: Int)
  def step(data: Iterations) = Coeval {
    val x = random()
    val y = random()
    val isInCircle = (x * x + y * y) < 1.0
    val newTotal = data.total + 1
    val newInCircle = data.inCircle + (if (isInCircle) 1 else 0)
    if (newTotal >= iterations) Right(newInCircle.toDouble / newTotal.toDouble * 4.0)
    else Left(Iterations(newTotal, newInCircle))
  }
  Monad[Coeval].tailRecM(Iterations(0, 0))(step).value
}
```

Comment: thanks! Do you see a way to inject the functional `RNG.Simple` from above and have it carry state through the computation instead of using a stateful `Random.nextDouble`?

Comment: In functional way you would be by using some IO monad for encapsulating side-effects (Cats' Effects IO, Monix's Task, Scalaz ZIO). Then you would receive result as `IO[Result]`. And run that IO in `main`. State monad is just a composition of functions `S => (S,A)`, you still would have to perform some side effects somewhere. If you just generated sequence of random data once, and then purely turn it into one result, then it's just a `foldLeft`, you don't need a monad for that.

Comment: I tried the first block of code that you provided above but it doesn't compile. The error is `value flatMap is not a member of type parameter F[Double] x <- random` (same for y). Am I missing something?

Comment: If your are using type classes and want to use syntax. you have to import this syntax as well. E.g. `cats.Monad` + `cats.syntax.monad._` or `scalaz.Monad` + `scalaz.syntax.monad._`. (or `cats._` + `cats.implicits._` or `scalaz._` + `Scalaz._`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that my friend [Charles Miller](https://fishbowl.pastiche.org/) came up with. It's a bit more direct since it uses `RNG` directly but it follows the same approach provided by @Mateusz Kubuszok above that leverages `Monad`.

The key difference is that it leverages the `State` monad so we can thread the `RNG` state through the computation and generate the random numbers using the "pure" random number generator.

```
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._

object PICharles {
  type RNG[A] = State[Long, A]

  object RNG {
    def nextLong: RNG[Long] =
      State.modify[Long](
        seed ⇒ (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFL
      ) >> State.get

    def nextInt: RNG[Int] = nextLong.map(l ⇒ (l >>> 16).toInt)

    def nextNatural: RNG[Int] = nextInt.map { i ⇒
      if (i > 0) i
      else if (i == Int.MinValue) 0
      else i + Int.MaxValue
    }

    def nextDouble: RNG[Double] = nextNatural.map(_.toDouble / Int.MaxValue)

    def runRng[A](seed: Long)(rng: RNG[A]): A = rng.runA(seed).value

    def unsafeRunRng[A]: RNG[A] ⇒ A = runRng(System.currentTimeMillis)
  }

  object PI {
    case class Step(count: Int, inCircle: Int)

    def calculatePi(iterations: Int): RNG[Double] = {
      def step(s: Step): RNG[Either[Step, Double]] =
        for {
          x ← RNG.nextDouble
          y ← RNG.nextDouble
          isInCircle = (x * x + y * y) < 1.0
          newInCircle = s.inCircle + (if (isInCircle) 1 else 0)
        } yield {
          if (s.count >= iterations)
            Right(s.inCircle.toDouble / s.count.toDouble * 4.0)
          else
            Left(Step(s.count + 1, newInCircle))
        }

      Monad[RNG].tailRecM(Step(0, 0))(step(_))
    }

    def unsafeCalculatePi(iterations: Int) =
      RNG.unsafeRunRng(calculatePi(iterations))
  }
}
```

Thanks Charles & Mateusz for your help!